# find_all not going to next item

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape multiple line items. I can get it to repeat the scrape twice but it's not finding all items, just the first item twice.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cloudjumper2000/2f2bef395811b8f25cc3a9c8e3834117/raw/54d71f17d7e2169006eb7d8963a0e176f1448efe/nemin_sample.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
    itemurl = soup.find('a', class_='product')
    print(itemurl.get('href'))

    image = soup.find('img', class_='lazy-load')
    print(image.get('data-src'))

    title = soup.find('div', class_='title').text
    print(title)

    #price = soup.find('div', class_='price')
    price = soup.find(class_='product-price').find(class_="price").text
    print(price)

    countdown = soup.find(class_='product-countdown')
    print(countdown.get('data-countdown'))

    watchlist = soup.find(class_='watchlist')
    print(watchlist.get('data-itemid'))

    print()
```

The output:

```
/Item/39138113
http://example.com/39138113-thumb.jpg
                    Item listing number 1

$6.99                                    
3/9/2018 6:48:45 AM
39138113
/Item/39138113
http://example.com/39138113-thumb.jpg
                    Item listing number 1

$6.99                                    
3/9/2018 6:48:45 AM
39138113
```

Here's the [HTML](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cloudjumper2000/2f2bef395811b8f25cc3a9c8e3834117/raw/54d71f17d7e2169006eb7d8963a0e176f1448efe/nemin_sample.html) I'm scraping.

Comment: You are using `soup` instead of `products` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
    itemurl = soup.find('a', class_='product')
```

The second `soup.find` call will return the first matching element in the entire document. To search *within* the matched `li` element, use `products.find` instead:

```
for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
    itemurl = products.find('a', class_='product')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `soup.find(...)`, you will always get the first element in the HTML matching your query. Because your loop finds two products, the query is repeated twice.

If I understand you correctly, you want to scrap each product for its image, price etc.? In that case, replace `soup.find(...)` with `products.find(...)` inside your for loop, e.g:

```
for products in soup.find_all('li', class_='widget'):
    itemurl = products.find('a', class_='product')
    ...
```